# Number of cells in a minimal cell structure for a non-simply connected manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have obtained a cell structure of a connected (but not simply connected) manifold using Morse theory. Is there any way for me to know whether this cell structure is minimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's far from a complete answer, the [Morse inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_inequalities) give you bounds. Namely if $C_i$ is the number of cells of dimension $i$ and if $\beta_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Betti number then
for any $i$ you have the Morse inequality
$$C_i - C_{i-1} + C_{i-2} - \cdots \pm C_0 \ge \beta_i - \beta_{i-1} + \beta_{i-2} - \cdots \pm \beta_0
$$

Comment: Here $C_i=M_i$.

Comment: Oops, right, thanks for the correction. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lee. Since the right hand side is just the Euler characteristic, if I know what this is for my manifold then will this give me a restriction on the cells that I have?

Comment: The right hand side is *not* the full Euler characteristic sum: it is a cut-off version of the Euler characteristic sum incorporating only the terms between $0$ and $i$. There is one Morse inequality for each value of $i$. For example, when $i=1$ you get $C_1 - C_0 \ge \beta_1 - \beta_0$, which holds regardless of the dimension, and so for a connected complex where $\beta_0=1$ you get $C_1 - C_0 \ge \beta_1 - 1$.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my mistake. Thanks for clearing up that misunderstanding.

Comment: A Morse function is perfect if all the Morse inequalities are equalities. This need not exist (for example on a homology three sphere such things do not exist).